# Will Hostname rename affect git

Tags: git, ubuntu, hostname

Todays topic: Git

I have a gitolite server and an ubuntu pc.

I have connected my ubuntu pc via ssh with the gitolite server and all is good.
Although, I did this withought knowning how ssh actually works.

If I change the hostname,the username,the home directory for the user I want to rename, on my ubuntu pc will it affect my git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you host name does not affect git, but username or homedir do.

SSH connection uses SSH-key files located in your `<home-directory>/.ssh/` folder. So, if you change the user - be sure your new home folder contains folder `.ssh/` with original files. I think you can backup the folder (.ssh) before you create/rename user and his home folder.

In case you want create a new SSH-key files - use `ssh-keygen` utility. It requires to add content of ssh public key to your user settings in gitolite server